# plotting 3D surface using python: raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.") matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 3d surface passes through a set of (X,Y,Z) 3d point and I got  raise ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.") matplotlib

```
points = Tail_geo(D,L) # is a list from a function 
points = points + Nose_geo(D,L)# is a list from both function s
X = [x[0] for x in points]# seperate X from the list
Y = [x[1] for x in points]
Z = [x[2] for x in points]
X = np.asarray(X)
Y = np.asarray(Y)
Z = np.asarray(Z)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
plt . show ( )
```

Comment: This code snippet is not complete, since you do not show the definitions of functions `Tail_geo` and `Nose_geo` and show no imports. Those things may matter. Please show a complete code snippet that we can copy-and-paste then run. Also show the complete traceback for the error. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It seems in your code `Z` is also a 1-D list. In a 3d surface, for a set of `X` and `X` points, you need a meshgrid of these `X` and `Y` points and then define/compute `Z` at each of these `n` times `n` grid (assuming `len(X) = n; len(Y) = n`). With the current data all you can plot is a 3d scatter plot. Plz share your code if you want more info.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The function `plot_surface` expects its inputs to be structured as a regular 2D grid.  For your data (x,y,z as lists) it would probably be more appropriate to use the `plot_trisurf` function.  Just make a simple replacement in your code.

```
surf = ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

There is a nice example in the matplotlib gallery here https://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/trisurf3d_demo.html which you can look through for some more details.